# Sass breaking due to CSS custom properties?

Tags: css, sass, mixins, css-variables

Say you have the CSS custom property for a color:

`--color: 255,0,0`

And you want to mix it specially every time with `rgb` or `rgba` as the need requires. This is valid CSS:

`rgba(var(--color), .3)`

...but Sass explodes. I've been trying to see if I could write a mixin or something but I can't figure out how to get around Sass's insistence on using it's own color functions even when they are not necessary.

Comment: For added context I know it explicitly has to be three digits in the way the variable is defined. And I've tested this in vanilla CSS, it works. This appears to be a bug where Sass doesn't know how to deal with custom properties yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got it! This is a bit hacky but this allows you to create a custom function that utilizes the `rgba()` function with CSS custom properties (as allowed in the spec):

```
@function swatch($swatch-color, $swatch-alpha:1) {
  @return unquote("rgba(var(--#{$swatch-color}), #{$swatch-alpha})");
}
:root {
  --green: 0,255,0;
}
.green { color: swatch(green, .1); }
```

Found the key to the solution in a [Sass bug report](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/469). This only works because the unquoting and interpolation bypass the default `rgba()` function.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps using [interpolation](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#interpolation_) `rgba(#{--color}, .3)`?

Comment: Comes back with an error of: `Error: argument `$color` of `rgba($color, $alpha)` must be a color`

Answer (score 2):

Another temporary workaround for this is to use RGB values only in your variables like you are already:

```
--color: 255, 255, 255;
```

Then if you use the RGB or RGBA function with **capitals**, SASS will ignore it and plain CSS is able to parse it. You can then adjust the opacity!

```
RGB(var(--color));
RGBA(var(--color), .3);
```

Answer (score -1):

rgba(var(--color), .3) is not valid:

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
  outline: 1px dashed black;
}

:root {
  --color: red;
}

#correct {
  background: var(--color);
}

#incorrect {
  background: rgba(var(--color), .3);
}
```

```html
<div id="correct"></div>
<div id="incorrect"></div>
```

Comment: `--color: red;` would make it invalid. Note how I'm using `--color: 255,0,0;`.

Comment: This works in pure CSS:

    :root { --color: 255,0,0; }
    div { background-color: rgba(var(--color), .3); }